# Obervable in obervable with conditions - Angular 10

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In a form I want to add a book.

The user manually enters the author's name. When the user submit the form it should check first if the author exists :

- if not it creates the author
- If it already exists it just retrieve authors information (id)
- Then it add the book with the author id

I think I can make it work with :

```
formSubmit() {
  this.authorService.getByName(this.authorName).subscribe(author => {
    // Author exists
    if (author.id) {
      this.book.author = author;
      this.bookService.add(this.book).subscribe(() => {
        // Book added
      });
    } else {
      const authorObj: AuthorInterface = {
        fullName = this.authorName;
      }
      this.authorService.add(authorObj); subscribe(author => {
        this.book.author = author;
        this.bookService.add(this.book).subscribe(() => {
          // Book added
        });
      })
    }
  });
}
```

But it's really horrible, I am sure I can make it cleaner with `rxjs` but can't find a solution. I am a bit confused about how to use all those functions.

I'll appreciate some help. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Some questions: The goal is to save the author in the book object? If you request a non existant author by name it still returns an author object but with no id? Why do you add the book if "Author exists"? I have an idea of your requirements and as far as I see the problem you can solve it with one subscription at runtime. Therefore I need answers to my three questions.

Comment: The goal is to save the book with the author, but if the author has already been added I want to retrieve it and add it to the book. Actually, this is an example I am not working on books and author but we can imagine that if the user does not exists API returns and empty object (I use API Platform for back). If the author exists I may want to add a new book that he just wrote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is a large observable (many emitted values) you better stay with if else

```
this.authorService
  .getByName(this.authorName)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((author: any) => {
      if (author.id) {
        this.book.author = author;
        return this.bookService.add(this.book).pipe(
          tap(() => {
            console.log("book added");
          })
        );
      } else {
        const authorObj: AuthorInterface = {
          fullName: this.authorName
        };
        return this.authorService.add(authorObj).pipe(
          mergeMap((author: any) => {
            this.book.author = author;
            return this.bookService.add(this.book).pipe(
              tap(() => {
                console.log("book added");
              })
            );
          })
        );
      }
    })
  )
  .subscribe(() => console.log("job done"));
```

alternatively you can do this:

```
  const firstObservable = this.authorService.getByName(this.authorName).pipe(
      filter((author: any) => author.id != null),
      mergeMap(author => {
        this.book.author = author;
        return this.bookService.add(this.book).pipe(
          tap(() => {
            console.log("book added");
          })
        );
      })
    );

    const secondObservable = this.authorService.getByName(this.authorName).pipe(
      filter((author: any) => author.id == null),
      mergeMap((author: any) => {
        const authorObj: AuthorInterface = {
          fullName: this.authorName
        };
        return this.authorService.add(authorObj).pipe(
          mergeMap((author: any) => {
            this.book.author = author;
            return this.bookService.add(this.book).pipe(
              tap(() => {
                console.log("book added");
              })
            );
          })
        );
      })
    );

    merge(firstObservable, secondObservable).subscribe(author =>
      console.log("job done")
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap). This operator subscribes to another observable you pass to it and outputs its result.

```
this.authorService.getByName(this.authorName)
.pipe(
  switchMap(author => {
    if (author.id) {
      this.book.author = author;
      return this.bookService.add(this.book).pipe(...);
    }
    return this.authorService.add(authorObj).pipe(
      switchMap(author => ...)
    );
  })
)
.subscribe();
```